# Stop a redirect in a Rails 3.1 action?

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, action

I'm doing some Rails stuff with AJAX (not using UJS, but rather rolling my own AJAX). My action looks like:

```
# DELETE /votes/1
# DELETE /votes/1.json
def destroy
  @vote = Vote.find(params[:id])
  Comment.increment @vote.comment_id, :up_votes => -1
  @vote.destroy

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to votes_url }
    format.json { head :ok }
  end
end
```

This action is being called via JavaScript ala:

```
   ajaxOptions = {
      url: $(this).attr("href"),
      type: $(this).attr("data-method"),
      data: {
        comment_id: $(this).attr("data-comment_id"),
        _method: 'delete'
      },
      success: function(response) {
        return someFunc();
      }
    };
    $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
```

However, what happens is the action redirects to the vote list page. I want it to not redirect at all just return some positive status to the JavaScript so that my `someFunc()` can execute without issue.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Are you sure `format.json` is correct? I usually see `format.js`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your respond_to handler to Javascript instead of JSON:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to votes_url }
  format.js { head :ok }
end
```

Comment: It still calls the redirect as if the html handler is running. Does the action know that it's being called via JavaScript?

Comment: Try adding a `format=js` parameter to the url, or a `.js` to the end of the path.